# How to fix inner grid - Matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, visualization

I have a problem with inner grids and y ticks being unevenly distributed (along left side of the box, bottom-top). Also, I'd like inner frame to be cropped at y=100 for all subplots (there are picks above y=100 and I don't want inner frame to show them).

How to accomplish that?

[image: three subplots]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "inner" grids/frame, but you can set where the ticks will be with `plt.yticks` and where the limits of the shown range are with `plt.ylim`. Your ticks and grid look evenly distributed, but the range limits are not, so maybe try `plt.ylim(0,100)` (or `ax.set_ylim(0,100)` if you're using an axes object).

Comment: It really helps if you provide a minimal example (including synthetic data) that will reproduce your issues.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer. Range limits were the problem (I'm using axes object):

```
 ax.set_ylim(0,100)
 ax.set_xlim(1992,2012)
```

[image: limit ticks]